# WordPress admin-ajax.php not available for subscribers/contributors

Tags: ajax

I've implemented a simple category ajax filter using admin-ajax.php that works perfectly if the user is not logged in or if the user is logged in as an administrator. For everyone else, it calls the homepage instead of respective category archive. No errors are thrown in the console.

I made sure to use the additional nopriv hook which is why this is baffling me.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_filter','filter_ajax');
```

I specifically need to make sure it works for Subscribers. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using the old legacy admin ajax API, have you considered sidestepping the problem with the modern REST API? It gives nicer URLs, responds in JSON automatically, and if you use it incorrectly you get a message saying what went wrong rather than a cryptic `0`

Comment: May I suggest posting the code for your `filter_ajax` method and the jQuery you are using to make the AJAX call?  The reason being is that it is likely that there is an error in your server side coding that is causing your client side ajax to behave the way its.